# C# - Making fields/properties read only conditionally

Tags: c#, immutability, readonly

I have three classes; Classes `A` and `B` both reference class `C`.

How can I make it so members of class `C` can be modified when referenced from class `A` but not modified when referenced from class `B`?

IE, the following should be possible;

```
classA myClassA = new classA();
myClassA.myClassC.IssueNumber = 3;
```

But this should not be possible;

```
classB myClassB = new classB();
myClassB.myClassC.IssueNumber = 3;
```

Making `classB.classC` read-only still allows properties of `classC` to be altered.

I'm sure this is basic stuff but can't find a simple answer.

Thanks,
A

Comment: You probably don't really want/need this. Can you provide a more specific example to clarify (i.e. use specific classes)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pattern 1: Make a simple read-only interface `IRead`. Make a simple write interface `IWrite`. Make an read-write interface `IReadWrite : IRead, IWrite`. Implement `classC : IReadWrite`. Declare `myClassA.myClassC` as `IReadWrite`. Declare `myClassB.myClassC` as `IRead`. (You don't have to user `IWrite` anywhere if you don't need it :-))

Pattern 2: create a read-only wrapper for `classC` called `ReadOnlyClassC` and use that one in `classB`.

Pattern 1 is used by the IO streams to split the reader and writer implementations and then combine them in read-write streams.

Pattern 2 is used by the generic collections to provide read-only facet.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it in C# as you would in C++. But you may define a readonly interface for class C that would be handled by B whereas A will handle the actual C.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to split class C to 2 classes:

```
class C
{
    protected int _IssueNumber;

    public int GetIssueNumber()
    {
        return _IssueNumber;
    }
}

class WritableC : C
{
    public void SetIssueNumber(int issueNumber)
    {
        _IssueNumber = issueNumber;
    }
}

class A
{
    public WritableC myClassC;
    ...
}

class B
{
    public C myClassC;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

As [Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/martinho-fernandes) said you can also use one class with 2 different interfaces:

```
interface IC
{
    int IssueNumber { get; }
}

interface IWritableC : IC
{
    int IssueNumber { get; set; }
}

class C : IWritableC
{
    protected int _IssueNumber;

    public IssueNumber
    {
        get { return _IssueNumber; }
        set { _IssueNumber = value; }
    }
}

class A
{
    public IWritableC myClassC;
    ...
}

class B
{
    public IC myClassC;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Another option is to keep a single C class, but with an explicitly implemented interface that exposes the setter.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign rights as such to specific classes. However, you can place Class A and Class C in the same assembly and Class B in another. Then define the `set` accessor for the property as `internal`. This means that it can only be set by classes in the same assembly:

```
public int IssueNumber
{
  get;
  internal set;
}
```

Alternatively, you could implement a method on Class A which sets the property value, but not on class B:

```
public void SetIssueNumber(int value)
{
  this.myClassA.IssueNumber = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have a boolean isReadOnly in ClassC. Set this boolean using a constructor. While creating instance of ClassC in ClassB call `ClassC myClassC = new ClassC(true);` In the set block of IssueNumber, check for the boolean value. If true alter the value

```
bool isReadOnly;
public ClassC(bool isReadOnly)
{
    this.isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
}

int _issueNumber;
public int IssueNumber
{
    get
    {
        return _issueNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!isReadOnly)
        {
            _issueNumber = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is that important to make this difference, make an interface:

```
// read only interface
interface IC
{
  int IssueNumber { get; }
}

class C : IC
{
  int IssueNumber { get; set; }
}

// get the full type from A
class A
{
  C MyClassC { get; }
}

// only get read only interface from B
class B
{
  IC MyClassC { get; }
}
```